# Define new unit in siunitx with angles and spaces

Tags: siunitx

I would like to define a unit to render

```
\SI{5}{\degTTh}
```

as

[image]

So far, I've been able to define a new unit

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\degTTh}{%
 \text{$^\circ\ 2\theta$}%
}
```

but there is a space between the numeral and the degree sign. Using the option `\SI[space-before-unit=false]{5}{\degTTh}` doesn't resolve the issue.

I've also tried declaring

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\TTh}{%
 \text{$\ 2\theta$}%
}
```

and then using `\SI[space-before-unit=false]{5}{\degree\TTh}`, but this also results in a space between the numeral and degree symbol.

.

How can I define such a unit?

Comment: Quick dirty fix: place a `\!` (it's a [negative space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-the-spacing-command) in math mode) in your 1st definition ==> `\text{$\!^\circ\ 2\theta$}%`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When creating a new unit with *siunitx*, you can override any key-value pair option by supplying it in the `<options>` field in

```
\DeclareSIUnit[<options>]{<unit>}{<definition>}
```

The symbol between the number and the unit is set with `number-unit-product`. In your case, you want to have *no* symbol between number and unit, i.e. `{}`.
The definition of your unit then becomes

```
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]{\degTTh}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree\ensuremath{~2\theta}}
```

Additionally, I replaced the `^\circ` with the symbol `\SIUnitSymbolDegree`, which is defined by *siunitx*.
Finally, I replaced the `$ ... $` with `\ensuremath`, as suggested in the package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}    % only to make all examples aligned.

\DeclareSIUnit{\degTThold}{\text{$^\circ\ 2\theta$}}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]{\degTTh}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree\ensuremath{~2\theta}}

\begin{document}

\SI{5}{\degTThold} \\
\SI{5}{\degTTh} \\
$x = \SI{5}{\degTThold}$ \\
$x = \SI{5}{\degTTh}$

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output]