# Latex siunitx declare unit

Tags: siunitx, units

I would like to declare the following unit:

dB re 1 $\mu$Pa

I found this answer:
[Define new unit in siunitx with angles and spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323943/define-new-unit-in-siunitx-with-angles-and-spaces)

And got this working:

```
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]{\dBpa}{\dB \micro \pascal}
```

But I would it like this:

```
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]{\dBpa}{\dB \text{re 1} \micro \pascal}
```

But the `\text` part does not work.

How could one include normal text in a unit?

EDIT:

Inside the document this works:

```
  \si{\dB \ensuremath{\text{ re } 1} \micro \pascal}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little detour it is possible to create the unit I wanted to create:

```
\DeclareSIUnit[]{\reference}{\ensuremath{~\text{ re } 1 }}
\DeclareSIUnit[]{\dBpa}{\dB \reference \micro \pascal}
```

So the text part is first declared as a separate SIUnit. This can then be used in the second declaration.