How to reduce the spacing before \degreeCelsius in siunitx?
How to reduce the spacing between the number and degree symbol in siunitx? I'm aware of the BIPM recommmendation to use a space, but couldn't find any typographic recommendations. I don't want to change the spacing before other units.

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[detect-mode]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\qty{1}{\degreeCelsius} in \qty{1}{\second}.
\end{document}

I've tried passing \! as part of the number. I've also tried recreating the degree definition using with things like
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {\,\!}]\degreeCelsius{^{\circ}C}

but can't make the symbol look like the original. I'm using LuaLaTeX in case that matters.

peraphs this can help you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323943/define-new-unit-in-siunitx-with-angles-and-spaces

@Sebastiano Thank you, so the degree symbol used is \SIUnitSymbolDegree

@Anna That's in v2 - your MWE shows you are using v3

You are on the right track: you just need to pick an appropriate definition for the symbol and tackle a timing issue (which I'll take a look at):
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[detect-mode]{siunitx}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = {}]\degreeCelsius
    {\ifmmode{}^{\circ}\else °\fi C}
}
\begin{document}
\qty{1}{\degreeCelsius} in \qty{1}{\second}.
\end{document}


On the typography, BIPM say there should be 'a space' before all units except degrees, and that does include degrees Celsius.

Thank you! With the typography, I just meant that they don't clarify the width of the spacing.  I'm aware of the recommmendation to use a space in this situation. (Apologies for my last comment, I misread your last sentence.)

@Anna True, they don't - the tradition of using a thin space is a typographic one. However, I do think it's clear that the same spacing should be used for all units.

I'll just add a note that after looking more at this, it turns out my issue was simply with the kerning between 1 and °, which is exaggerated in my current font (Minion with old-style digits). All other digits turn out fine. As there was just a single occurence, I hacked together a solution. Thank you again for consistent support on a stellar package!
