# What is the symbol (\!) for?

Tags: syntax

I have been copying from class text to a blade on Sharelatex, and it seems the teachers use the symbol (`\!`) a lot.

```
\sin\!\left(x\right)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}
\cos\!\left(\frac{\pi }{12}\right)
```

Why do they need to use the symbol for exclamation mark(!) ?

Comment: it's a small negative space which here will move the bracket closer to the trig function, perhaps partly to alleviate the fact that `\left` and `\right` are totally unnecessary in the first example and will give inferior results. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing

Comment: Also: It is `\!` not `!`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-the-spacing-command/9255

Comment: That is really poor latex style to copy.

Comment: see item 2 in the accepted answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing

Comment: You could *politely* suggest to your teacher to try `texdoc mleftright`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know if I would dare :)